# How to plot line graphs in plotly and change graphs based on button pressed

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

Following is my code

```
# imports
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd


# plotly figure setup
fig = go.Figure()

# one trace for each df column
for brand in final_df2.brand.unique():
    df = final_df2[final_df2.brand == brand]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.date, y=[df["price"].values,df["SHB Car price"].values],
                             name = brand,
                             mode = 'lines')
                 )
    
    

# one button for each df column
updatemenu= []
buttons=[]
for brand in final_df2.brand.unique():
    df = final_df2[final_df2.brand == brand]
    buttons.append(dict(method='restyle',
                        label=brand,
                        args=[{'y':[df["price"].values, df["SHB Car price"].values]}])
                  )

# some adjustments to the updatemenu
updatemenu=[]
your_menu=dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu)
updatemenu[0]['buttons']=buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction']='down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive']=True

# update layout and show figure
fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenu)
fig.show()
```

And here is what the final_df2 looks like:
[image]

There should be a button for each brand and when that button is pressed SHB Car price and price should be displayed. However using the above code cluters all the graphs in one like this:
[image]

This is what the dataframe looks like:

```
 {'date': {11: Timestamp('2020-04-21 00:00:00'),
      12: Timestamp('2020-04-22 00:00:00'),
      14: Timestamp('2020-04-24 00:00:00'),
      17: Timestamp('2020-04-24 00:00:00'),
      19: Timestamp('2020-04-24 00:00:00'),
      22: Timestamp('2020-04-26 00:00:00'),
      23: Timestamp('2020-04-26 00:00:00'),
      25: Timestamp('2020-04-26 00:00:00'),
      27: Timestamp('2020-04-27 00:00:00'),
      28: Timestamp('2020-04-27 00:00:00')},
     'SHB Car price': {11: 65950.0,
      12: 80000.0,
      14: 81500.0,
      17: 104500.0,
      19: 155000.0,
      22: 88500.0,
      23: 89750.0,
      25: 99000.0,
      27: 65900.0,
      28: 107000.0},
     'price': {11: nan,
      12: nan,
      14: nan,
      17: nan,
      19: nan,
      22: nan,
      23: nan,
      25: nan,
      27: nan,
      28: nan},
     'brand': {11: 'opel',
      12: 'opel',
      14: 'opel',
      17: 'toyota',
      19: 'volvo',
      22: 'kia',
      23: 'nissan',
      25: 'toyota',
      27: 'dacia',
      28: 'kia'}}
```

This dataframe contains different brands in brand column. For each brand I need to plot SHB car price and price

Comment: https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/

Comment: You have added `df["price"].values,` to the y-axis value, does this make sense?